# Include Deleted Data along with other data into Audit Query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am querying as following

```
AuditQuery si_query = audQueryCreator.forRevisionsOfEntity(SecurityIdentifiers.class, false, false)
                                .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().eq(revision_Id));
```

Above Query doesn't contain deleted data (data with revision type '2').

If I add following code

```
si_query.add(AuditEntity.revisionType().eq(RevisionType.DEL));
```

then it fetch only deleted data, that I don't want.

I want deleted data along with inserted data and modified data.

This query brings all other data except deleted one.

So Please tell me how to query to include deleted data too.

Comment: does `.add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().eq(revision_Id)).add(AuditEntity.revisionType().eq(RevisionType.DEL));` not work ?

Comment: No, It gives only deleted data.
 I want other data too along with deleted as I mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your usage, particularly the last argument but also perhaps the second too.

In order to have deleted rows returned in the results, you have to specify the last argument to that method as `true`.  The method java documentation for that argument says:

> If true, also revisions where entities were deleted will be returned. The additional entities will have revision type "delete", and contain no data (all fields null), except for the id field.

My next concern is your expected result object type.  This is related to the second argument to the method.  The method java documentation for that argument says:

> If true, instead of a list of three-element arrays, a list of entities will be returned as a result of executing this query.

So the question is whether you expect the returned list of values to be the actual audited entity instances or whether you expect it to be a `List<Object[]>` where each object array row contains a specific set of values.

By specifying `true`, the result is `List<Object>` but `false` it's `List<Object[]>`.

If you use `false`, each row will consist of:

1. The entity instance.
2. The revision entity instance. (the revision number and date).
3. The revision type (ADD, MOD, DEL).

HTH.

Comment: Thank You so much, I had a confusion in usage of **true, false**  now your explanation makes it clear.